# grep html file from wget

Tags: html, grep, wget

I use wget to download number of papers matching a given query in scholar.google.com 
and I obtain a file which shows all the content of the page.

I want to retrieve the last number in the following part of the file
"Results 1 - 10 of about 8,890."

I tried:

```
 cat /dir/file | tr -d "," | grep -o -E -- 'about ([^"]+) \w+'
```

but it outputs:

```
 about <b>8890</b>.   (<b>0.12</b> sec)&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table></form>    <div class
```

whereas I just want the 8890 (with no comma which is taken care by tr -d ","

any suggestion on how to improve it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html tags (`<b>` and `</b>`) are present in your file, you'll have to modify your regex to take care of them too. To get just the fragment you're interested in use a lookbehind assertion. Here's something that should work:
`cat /dir/file | tr -d "," | grep -oP -- '(?<=about <b>)[^/<> ]+'`

Answer (score 3):

Grep pulls out the right line - use sed after that to chop away what you don't want.

```
 cat /dir/file | tr -d "," | grep -o -E -- 'about ([^"]+) \w+' |sed -e 's/.*about <b>//' -e 's/<.b>.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: `sed -n 's#.*about <b>\([0-9]*\)</b>.*#\1#p'` instead of `grep`.

`-n` means don't print input lines as default, `s` flag `p` means print if substituted.